# How to get the total number of comments on a linkedin company?

Tags: linkedin-api

Not able to get more than 100 posts in single Rest API Call for the linkedin Company updates.

Is there anyway which we can get more than 100 updates.

https://developer.linkedin.com/reading-company-shares

Answer (score 1):

The count parameter has a limit on the number of comments you can fetch in one call. Try setting this to a very high number, e.g. 500. If you still get 100 results, it means hundred is the maximum you can get. In that case, you need to play with the start parameter, but it won't be all in one API call.

So here is how it goes

> start=0&count=100 - Fetches the first 100 results
>
> start=100&count=100 - Fetches the second 100 results

This is impossible using one API call as you can see, but better than nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your information. So is there anyway which we can get filtered based on dates.. Suppose if today i have loaded the data tommorow i have to get only recent updates.. Is this possible ? If yes can you suggest me the way

Comment: You will always get the latest network updates at that time. Impossible to filter by date range.